# Enable SQL Server to distingush between - (U+002D) and － (U+FF0D)

Tags: sql, sql-server, special-characters

If SQL Server is set up to consider - (U+002D) and － (U+FF0D) to be the same thing, i.e.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN 'AB-CD' = 'AB－CD' 
       THEN 'SAME' 
       ELSE 'DIFFERENT' 
    END
```

would yield "SAME", is there a way to make it distinguish between those (and generally all) characters, i.e. to yield "DIFFERENT"?

I can't change the setup of the whole environment.

I know there is an option to make one specific SQL comparison case sensitive even if the general setup is case insensitive, by stating

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN 'A' = 'a' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS 
       THEN 'SAME' 
       ELSE 'DIFFERENT' 
    END
```

Is there a similar "trick" to make SQL "sensitive" for different special characters?

Comment: *"Is there a similar "trick" to make SQL "sensitive" for different special characters?"* No, a collation is either Case Sensitive *or* Case Insensitive . It cannot be a bit Case Sensitive and a bit Insensitive. It's one or the other.

Comment: Those characters are hyphens with different sizes. This has nothing to do with case sensitivity. The *collation* decides whether those two hyphens are considered the same or not. Most humans would consider them the same. If you don't want that, use a binary collation instead, eg `Latin1_General_100_BIN2`

Comment: BTW all `SQL_` and `_BIN` collations are considered deprecated.

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos; @larnu; I know the answer because I'm living in an Unicode country.

Comment: @XAMT everyone is living in a Unicode country - those characters behave the same in the US. In fact, they first appeared in word processors created in the US.

Comment: Seen that the accepted answer indeed is a collation, I do not understand the downvote of the question. Could you (whowever downvoted or sees the reason) elaborate on that? How should I rephrase it to be more useful for future users having the same question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those characters are hyphens with different sizes. This isn't about case sensitivity. The collation decides whether those two hyphens are considered the same or not. Most humans would consider them the same.

If you don't want that, you can use a binary collation instead, eg Latin1_General_100_BIN2. Binary collations compare strings at the byte level and no linguistic rules are applied.

You should also ensure that *both* strings are Unicode, otherwise the long hyphen gets replaced with a normal hyphen.

This query will return `SAME` :

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN N'AB-CD' = N'AB－CD'
       THEN 'SAME' 
       ELSE 'DIFFERENT' 
    END
```

while this one returns `DIFFERENT`

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN N'AB-CD' = N'AB－CD' collate Latin1_General_100_BIN2
       THEN 'SAME' 
       ELSE 'DIFFERENT' 
    END
```

Finally, don't use collations [with the `SQL_` prefix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15#SQL-collations) or [`_BIN` suffix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15#Binary-collations). They are deprecated and only there for backwards compatibility

Answer (score -1):

The answer is Big N behind the Unicode `NVARCHAR` with the database set to Accent Sensitive collation like `Persian_100_CI_AS`:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN N'AB-CD' = N'AB－CD' 
        THEN 'SAME' 
        ELSE 'DIFFERENT' 
    END
```

Or you can set Collate in run time :

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN N'AB-CD' COLLATE Persian_100_CI_AS = N'AB－CD'  COLLATE Persian_100_CI_AS
        THEN 'SAME' 
        ELSE 'DIFFERENT' 
    END
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos; Your Database should set to Accent Sensitive collation like Persian_100_CI_AS

Comment: Changing the *database* collation isn't a solution. It won't change the collation of any existing columns. And forcing an accent-*sensitive* collation will break most queries

Comment: It's still wrong because it depends on language and collation rules. `Latin1_General_CI_AS` will return `SAME`. The two characters aren't *accented*